# What is this grammatical form called and how should punctuation be used

Tags: punctuation, objects

I am trying to find the correct punctuation for the following sentence:

> It allows connection to, and customisation of, functions available in the program.

1. Does such construction, with two direct objects, one sort of clarifying the other one, have a name? I was trying to use Google to answer my second question, but failed to explain to it what I mean.
2. What is the correct punctuation to use here? A colleague of mine suggested moving the second comma ahead to before “of”. I am in doubt.

Comment: No. I agree with your punctuation. The important thing about parenthetical commas, is that if you eliminate the words between the commas the sentence should still make grammatical sense. And this it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) The phrase or information can be called several things: parenthetical, nonessential, non-restrictive, or an aside.
- 2a) You want to use either two commas or none; which of these depends on if you view *and customization of* to be an essential part of the sentence or a useful, but ultimately unnecessary, addition.
- 2b) Moving the location of the comma would result in something ungrammatical if you were to remove the nonessential information:

  > It allows connection to *[, and customization,]* of functions available in the program.